# Zooming and panning on a floorplan made with Raphaeljs

Tags: zooming, raphael, pan

I am making some kind of floor plan that shows the position of participants of a meeting.
For this I am using Raphael.js.

I am looking to find a way to zoom & pan trough that floorplan but I am not finding anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing any of your code that defines the rest of the functionality go to
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=paper.setviewbox
Also use the raphael link to the documentation which always points to the latest....

There are some powerful new features in Raphael 2 that are not currently widely used.
Whats nice about this is that its just an add on!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also found that using setViewBox was a pretty good way to solve my problem.

Now I am using it to do the zooming I wanted. For panning I'm not sure how to use setViewBox for it? Any recommendations there?

Comment: Just because you cannot see all through 1 zoom and pan does not mean your off screen elements do not exist.

Comment: I know that. But I don't understand how i can use SetViewbox for panning? Should I just set x and y coordinates of the setviewbox method? Something like that:

paper.setViewBox(200,200,500,500); and say paper.setViewBox(400,200,500,500); to pan to the right?